# ADXL345 Accelerometer data rate vs bandwidth

Tags: accelerometer, bandwidth, baudrate, mems, data-rate

I recently started working with the ADXL345 Accelerometer and got a bit confused on what's the difference between the data rate and bandwidth.

From the [ADXL345 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADXL345.pdf) p14, we can see the different available data rates and bandwidth :

[image: Output Data rates and Bandwidth that can be used]

What confuses me more than anything is why don't they have the same values? Is the Output Data Rate, the rate of the data sent from the accelerometer to a microcontroller, or is that the bandwidth? I'm a bit confused so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that this is connected to the 'Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem', which says that for sampling frequency fs, only signals with frequencies lower than fs/2 can be converted without the loss (or signals with bandwidth smaller than fs/2).

Comment: Does that mean that, the acceloremter is measuring data at a rate of 50 Hz and sending it at a rate of 100 Hz to a micro-controller? for example?

Comment: @B.Adlane no, that means that the circuit is messuring (sampling) and sending data at 50hz, but that corresponds to maximum 25hz physical signal on accelometer. In other words: if accelometer is attached to oscillator with 25hz frequency you need at least 50hz sampling frequency to process that informattion without a loss